# LD_LIBRARY_PATH working but LD_PRELOAD not working

Tags: c, compilation

I have 2 files: ./a.out and libasm.so,

I can execute by using LD_LIBRARY_PATH without any problem:

```
$> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD
$> ./a.out
42
```

But, if I reset the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and I use LD_PRELOAD, it doesn't work anymore:

```
$> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
$> LD_PRELOAD=./libasm.so ./a.out
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libasm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What should I do to fix that problem ? I must use LD_PRELOAD to make it works (and no LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

The compilation is as below:

```
$> gcc main.c -L. -lasm
```

And the library has been created with the following command:

```
$> nasm -f elf64 strlen.S -o strlen.o && gcc -shared strlen.o -o libasm.so
```

ldd command gives the following:

```
$> ldd ./a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdda9fe000)
    /home/Nicolas/rendu/Assembleur/asm_minilibc/libasm.so (0x00007fb468f28000)
    libasm.so => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb468b48000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000555c0b2dd000)

$> ldd /home/Nicolas/rendu/Assembleur/asm_minilibc/libasm.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe09bc000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb3390c2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055789183a000)

$> ls -l /home/Nicolas/rendu/Assembleur/asm_minilibc/libasm.so
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 Nicolas Nicolas 7728 18 mars  14:24 /home/Nicolas/rendu/Assembleur/asm_minilibc/libasm.so
```

Two lines refers to libasm.so, the first one is correctly found, but the second one is not found. Why is there 2 lines instead of one ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: "I must use LD_PRELOAD" - why must you?

Comment: this is a subject in my school and the subject is allowing us to use LD_PRELOAD (but not LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Comment: Missing `export` when  setting `LD_PRELOAD`.  And don't include `a.out` in the list.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the full (i.e. absolute) path for `libasm.so`?

Comment: @Peter no, it's valid to pass cmd args like that.  
@void what is result of `ldd a.out`

Comment: Same thing with absolute path, @Peter, I have updated my post to display the result of ldd a.out, thank you very much

Comment: You probably forgot the `linux` tag.

Comment: What's the output from `ldd /home/Nicolas/rendu/Assembleur/asm_minilibc/libasm.so`, `file /home/Nicolas/rendu/Assembleur/asm_minilibc/libasm.so`, and `ls -l /home/Nicolas/rendu/Assembleur/asm_minilibc/libasm.so`?  It seems your `libasm.so` shared object might have a dynamic dependency on itself, which could explain your observed behavior.  How was `libasm.so` created?

Comment: libasm.so has been created with the following command: "nasm -f elf64 strlen.S -o strlen.o && gcc -shared strlen.o -o libasm.so" (it's an Assembly code), btw I have updated my topic to display the output of what you asked, thank you very much

Comment: @void Well, so much for that idea. Could you post two sets of output from `ldd -v a.out`, once without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set, and once with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set so that your program runs sucessfully?  Your question about the two `libasm.so` output lines seems to be the critical one.  *Why* are there two instances of `libasm.so` being looked for?  The output from `file libasm.so` might be useful, too, along with `objdump -p a.out | grep NEEDED` and `objdump -p libasm.so | grep NEEDED`.  Because there certainly seems to be something strange going on.

Comment: Maybe you can start it with `LD_DEBUG=all LD_PRELOAD=./libasm.so ./a.out`, this could shed some light on this issue